# Set value of row above

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have this script that, when a cell in column F is modified, adds "done" in column G:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.columnStart !== 6) return;
  e.range.offset(0, 1)
    .setValue('done')
}
```

This is what I managed to get, but I need more; I would like the script to do the following:

- When a cell in column F is modified, it adds in column G - instead of the value "done" - the value of the cell above it in column G. That is to say, if F10 is modified, G10 is modified with the value of G9.
- BUT, the script must not be triggered if F10 is emptied. As of now, if i clear the content of the whole row 10, then the script will automatically add a value in G10, which is of course not what I want.

I tried tons of things, but I'm too limited with Javascript to go any further... Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You already included a condition. Have you tried to add more conditions?

Comment: For example, "F10" was modified, you can retrieve a value of "G9" using ``e.range.offset(-1, 1).getValue()``. And you can already put a value to "G10". These can be used for your issue 1. Value that is put to a cell can be retrieved by ``e.value``. If the value of the cell is removed, the property of ``e.value`` becomes ``undefined``. This and Rubén's comment can be used for your issue 2.

Comment: Actually, I managed after an hour of trial and error to add another condition that I didn't include in the code I posted because it wasn't relevant to my questions. 
So yes, I have tried to add more conditions, but I always fail with even the most basic javascript syntax.

For example, Tanaike suggests to add "e.range.offset(-1, 1).getValue()" but I'm not even sure where to add it, nor if I should add something else in order for it to work. I can try, I may find after an hour, but it is be easier with help :(

Comment: @Kev I'm really sorry for the inconvenience. When the sample situation is it in your question, I think that ``e.range.offset(-1, 1).getValue()`` is used for retrieving "G9". You want to put it to "G10". And at that time, you don't want to put it when the value of "F10" is removed. When these situation is reflected to your script, how about modifying from ``e.range.offset(0, 1).setValue('done')`` to ``if (e.value) e.range.offset(0,1).setValue(e.range.offset(-1,1).getValue())``?

Comment: @Tanaike Wonderful, thank you very much. 
I am the one who is sorry, I really should learn javascript!

Comment: @Kev Thank you for replying. If you could confirm that the script works, can you post the modified script and accept it as a resolved answer? By this, I think that it will help other users who have the same situation.

Comment: @Kev Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Tanaike suggested, this solution works perfectly:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.columnStart !== 6) return;
  if (e.value) e.range.offset(0,1)
.setValue(e.range.offset(-1,1).getValue())
}
```

Thanks to them!